# I rounded my buttons via CSS and now they cascade

Tags: css, html

I used the two border options to round various buttons in my site and because of this, they now cascade by roughly one line break. (See image: http://gyazo.com/14af343dea8b280262f6c88465659c42 )

The HTML and CSS is pretty much the same for each button, so I posted an example. Any ideas on why this is happening (I imagine it's the div tags) and how I can stop it?

EDIT - JS Fiddle upload: http://jsfiddle.net/4phcS/

CSS:

```
#linkwordpress
{
    color:white;
    background-color:#5C0DAC;
    font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    top:-90px;
    left:500px;
    line-height:28px;
    border:2px solid;
    border-radius:25px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="linkwordpress">
    <a href="../wordpress">Wordpress</a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the markup including your buttons and their related css?  It is difficult to tell what the problem is without more code.

Comment: What do you mean by `cascade`?

Comment: We need more code to see what the problem is..., try to make a JsFiddle if possible

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit with an actual button and not my header.

By cascade I mean, each button drops by roughly a linebreak from the previous. My buttons look something like a staircase.

Comment: Can you be more specific or include an image of what your attempting to accomplish?

Comment: I just want my buttons to be on the same line, no vertical change in height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, but if I had to guess I would say that the fact that you are using a div is probably why.

Divs inherently have a `display:block`. Try changing the display to `inline` or `inline-block`.

```
#linkwordpress
{
    color:white;
    background-color:#5C0DAC;
    font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    position:relative;
    top:-90px;
    left:500px;
    line-height:28px;
    border:2px solid;
    border-radius:25px;
    display:inline;
}
```

or if your id #linkwordpress is just a container then add the `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block;` to the `anchor` inside of the div instead like so:

```
#linkwordpress a {
    display:inline-block;
    }
```

The best solution would be to remove the `<div>` from around the anchors entirely and negate the problem you are suffering with the `display` property. Like this:

```
    <nav>
    <div>
        <a class="Menu-Item" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="Menu-Item" href="about.html">About</a>
        <a class="Menu-Item" href="cv.html">CV</a>
        <a class="Menu-Item" href="../wordpress">Wordpress</a>
        <a class="Menu-Item" href="../webshop/catalog">Webshop</a>
    </div>
```

**EDIT:**
After examining your code I noticed several issues you were running into that were breaking the navigation. I've attached a new [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Incredulous/j4ZbT/) that I think accomplishes what you are looking for and will attempt to explain some of the changes below:

http://jsfiddle.net/Incredulous/j4ZbT/

You had free floating elements in your `<div id="container">` that needed to be put into another `div` and treated as a column.

I added 2 divs to your code:

```
<div id="col2">
    <div id="sideboxhead">Who am I?</div>
    <!-- lots of content here -->
</div>
<div id="col1">
    <div id="header2">Home</div>
    <!-- lots of content here -->
</div>
```

Then added the matching CSS to treat these as columns:

```
#col1 { float:left;width:644px;}
#col2 { float:right; width:145px;}
```

I also altered all of the `width` properties of divs in `#col1` so that I could apply the `width` to the entire column instead.

I removed all of your `top:XXpx;` values because you were artificially attempting to create/reduce space and instead added a `margin` value to the `nav` element that can be negative instead.

Lastly I removed all of your `left` values and instead added `float` to the columns. If you still want the offset of your center content area you can add another container `div` around both of the `#col2` & `#col1`, make its width less, then change the width of `#col1` by the difference of old width - new width.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to HTML and am fiddling. Inline block messes up the body of my page and throws some of my buttons to the corner for some reason while Inline just shrinks down the the button to it's smallest

Comment: We need to see your page, I see from your code that you have a `width:800px;` which sounds to me much more like the container that should be holding your individual buttons.

Comment: Sorry I originally had my header's html and CSS, I have now editted my post  to contain the relevant code. I will post a screenshot in just a second as my site is currently running from my desktop without a webserver

Comment: Post the code via jsfiddle so we can see it. The screen shot only confirms what you've already written. We need to see the code to understand the problem.

Comment: I have posted the jsfiddle

Comment: @Stormie I've looked at your JSFiddle and altered my answer based on what I've seen there. Let me know if this makes sense. http://jsfiddle.net/Incredulous/j4ZbT/

Comment: So where I attempted to shrink down gaps with pixel offsets I actually created the problem.. :c

Thanks you very much!

Comment: It was part of the problem, but not what you had originally asked about. You will see in the code on the JSfiddle that I posted that I took out all of the individual `divs` in your `<nav>` and instead put the `.menu-item` on the `<a class="menu-item">`, this took out like 10 lines and cleaned up the code a bit. That was your original problem, the `<div>` around the `<a>` anchors. I've added this to my answer so you can see what I'm referring to. The rest of it was a fix for some of the other problems you were no doubt still trying to fix.

Comment: Yes, I'm breezing through the majority of my issues now though. Thank you very much for helping me when I could barely form a proper question!

Comment: I payed it forward. I got a huge helping hand from someone yesterday in the same way on [this page](http://www.tradewelltax.com/blog/2014/03/03/your-money-mike-march-1-2014) which uses some of the same techniques you were using.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use id's (#), use classes instead as follows:

```
.header {
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:#5C0DAC;
  font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size:30px;
  padding:0px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  height:38px;
  width:800px;
  border:2px solid;
  border-radius:25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

And use display: inline-block.

```
<div class="header">
       Leon's CS150 Assignment
</div>
<div class="header">
       Leon's CS150 Assignment 2
</div>
```

Comment: All this does is relegate my buttons to list items and even then, it overlaps with my main body?

Comment: What do you mean by overlapsing? Please post the full code via jsfiddle, or at least take a screenshot.

Comment: I have now posted a screenshot, the posted code is all I have relating to my buttons unless you would like the full file for my index page?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

After reading your comment, the reason your items are *vertical* rather than *horizontal* is because the element that contains your navigation requires one of these two tags:

- `display: inline;`
- `display: inline-block;`

Those two items force the items to remain on the same line, rather then constantly drop to a new line.  Think of a nesting doll, each doll is one layer deep diving further and further into the doll.  Same applies to html, so to counter act that line drop per an element you modify the dimensions, float, or display to cater the design to your entire goal.

---

I'm still not entirely sure what your attempting to create, or do.  Is this more inline of what your trying to accomplish? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DbB4d/)

When you look at the code it isn't all that much different then yours.  One of the primary differences, is that `nav` is simply a `div` but it is anchoring to the parent element.  In this case `header`.  So I define this element as a `position: absolute;` which will allow more finite control over the entire menu structure.

Then for large menu's and refactoring sometimes it is better to utilize a `div` over the traditional `ul` or plain `a href`.  This will add a higher level of control yet again over your menu structure.

Also you'll notice that I don't use `Id`.  That is because an `Id` is only allowed on a single page, it is unique.  Which means it can't be utilized more than once.  A `class` can be, which is more inline for a repetitive values throughout your page.

I'm still not entirely sure of your goal and or poor wording of the question, but hopefully this points you in the proper direction:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;

    background: #5C0DAC;
}

h3 {
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;

    position: absolute;
    left: 85px;
}

.Menu-Item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;

    padding: 10px 35px;
    border-radius: 25px;

    display: inline;
    margin: 0px 15px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

a {
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    text-align: center;  
    line-height: 28px;
    color: white;
}
```

The `html`:

```
<header>
    <h3>Leon's CS150 Assignment</h3>
    <nav>
        <div class="Menu-Item">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </div>

        <div class="Menu-Item">
            <a href="#">About</a>
        </div>

        <div class="Menu-Item">
            <a href="#">CV</a>
        </div>

        <div class="Menu-Item">
            <a href="#">Wordpress</a>
        </div>

        <div class="Menu-Item">
            <a href="#">Webshop</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'm sorry that my question came across so convoluted.